# Renaming columns in pandas not working after Grouper data manipulation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've imported a dataset as a dataframe from Excel and performed some manipulations using grouper, value_counts, etc. This manipulation has seemed to create two column names that are the same (even though the values in said columns are not the same). I am having trouble renaming these columns so there are no duplicate names.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_excel('Example.xlsx',
                    usecols=("A:F"), sheet_name=('Data'))

df_Test1 = df_Test.drop_duplicates(subset=["API Number", "Chemical"], keep="first")
df_Test2 = df_Test1.copy()

df_Test2.loc[:, "JobStartDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df_Test2.loc[:, "JobStartDate"])
df_Test2["Chemical"].value_counts()
df_Test2.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="JobStartDate", freq="M"))["Chemical"].value_counts()
df_Test3 = df_Test2.groupby(["Chemical", pd.Grouper(key="JobStartDate", freq="M")])["Chemical"].value_counts().to_frame("Count")

print(df_Test3)

with pd.ExcelWriter("Example.xlsx",
                     mode="a", if_sheet_exists="replace") as writer:
     df_Test3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Test3")
```

The output is:

```
                                          Count
Chemical      JobStartDate Chemical            
HCl           2021-01-31   HCl                3
              2021-06-30   HCl                2
              2022-02-28   HCl                1
Hydrochloride 2021-01-31   Hydrochloride      1
              2021-06-30   Hydrochloride      2
acid          2021-01-31   acid               1
              2021-06-30   acid               2
              2022-02-28   acid               1
water         2021-01-31   water              1
              2021-06-30   water              2
              2022-02-28   water              1
```

and the output written into Excel is:
[Excel Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bv1ZH.png)

My goal is to plot the Count vs JobStartDate for each Chemical (far left column) so a series of line plots. But the two columns named "Chemical" are seeming to cause issues. I've tried to rename the columns using a few methods such as df_Test3.rename and adding inplace=True with no success. Sometimes the code runs with no errors but the column labels don't change, other times I've had errors such as "only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices" or cannot unpack non-iterable bool object.

I think it has something to do with the "Count" column label being above the others in the pycharm output? I'm not sure why or how that works. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: When you define `df_Test3`, you either want to group by **just** `pd.Grouper(key="JobStartDate", freq="M")`, and take the `value_counts` of Chemical, or you want to group by both of them and then just do `size`. What you have now is entirely redundant, leading to that unnecessary repeated level.

Comment: From a look at the output, it is possible both "Chemical" columns are in the index.  Perhaps try [`.droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html), and drop the last index level.  Perhaps this works?